# verify.js validate on submit button click

Tags: validation, client-side-validation

Hi I am using [verifyjs](http://verifyjs.com) to validate my form. But I want to write some code on submit button click and if form validate, I never want to submit form, I am just using 'form' for validation.
`$('form').valid()`  is not valid, how can i validate my form on button click?
So;

```
 <form>
        <input type="text" data-validate="number" />

        <input type="radio" name="a" value="asd" data-validate="required" />
        <input type="radio" name="a" value="asd1" data-validate="required" />
        <input type="radio" name="a" value="asd2" data-validate="required" />
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="abc();" />
    </form>
<script>


function abc() {
    if ($('form').valid()) { // like this. But valid() is not working in verifyjs. 


        alert('ok');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more careful when using tags.  The [tag:jquery-validate] plugin is not the same as `verify.js`.

Comment: You can't use `.valid()` because it is not a method provided to you by the `verify.js` plugin.  `.valid()` does not exist.  The documentation does not seem to provide a method for a boolean test of the form.

Comment: Sparky, Thanks for your answer, I already dont use. I just want to know, If there is a method like in jquery-validate.

Comment: AS per docs, Verify does not appear to have a method that's functionally equivalent to `.valid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#my-form").validate(...)` for complete form or
`$("#my-text-input").validate(...)` for inputs